# Phase shift at half the switching frequency of a dc-dc converter

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, buck, stability

I would like to know if, regardless of the control loop used (Voltage mode control, average current mode control, peak/valley current mode control), there is always a 90-degree phase drop at FSW/2 due to the sampling behaviour of the system ? I'm not sure because in case of an current mode control we have 2 loops so the outerloop can act as a non-sampled system.

Comment: Hello, I recommend you look at this [thesis](https://vtechworks.lib.vt.edu/items/253dc489-3ed0-430b-b3f4-9c82554e3c81) which goes deep in analyzing the impact of harmonics in the frequency response of a switching converter.

Comment: Thank you @VerbalKint

Comment: You can also look at this [document](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~tymerski/ece317/ECE317%20L8%20System%20Modelling%20Example_2.pdf) from Richard Tymerski in which the author details the frequency response of a basic converter.

Comment: Great, thanks again, I will read them both …  Because I'm a bit puzzled about the phase drop at Fsw/2 , the real reason ... for me ( in reflection ) it's purely due to Shanon's theorem (if sampling frequency < 2*max freq ,we're not able to reconstitute the sampled information so it's normal to have this phase drop ... but how much phase drop , how tondetermine that and so on ... I'll dwell on the documents you sent